# How do I restore my lost Address Book entries on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, restore, contacts

My mom just got a new iPhone 4S today, so she wanted me to transfer the contacts on her old iPhone 3G to the 4S. However, I screwed up.

And I don't have a single backup, so now, all I have is a copy of the contacts on her computer, and no real contacts.

Do any of you know how to fix this? Restore the old data?

Comment: What kind of computer does she have, Mac or PC? What are the contacts stored in (e.g., Microsoft Outlook, Mail, Mozilla Thunderbird, etc.)?

Comment: Was the iPhone synced with the computer at all?

Comment: It was the first time I installed iTunes on her computer after a restore, so I had no previous backups.

All the old contacts are lost.

Comment: Sorry to say: Zero backups equal zero restoration opportunities.

Comment: What does this statement mean?  "all I have is a copy of the contacts on her computer" If you have a copy then you have the contacts.

Comment: You should change the question: "How can I restore my contacts I do not have?"

Answer (score 1):

Check if she's stored the contacts anywhere else, such as in Hotmail, Gmail, Outlook, Apple Mail, etc.  You can pull them into the phone by linking an account in **Settings**, **Mail, Contacts, Calendars**, **Add Account...**, or you can synchronize with the PC by going through the iPhone options in iTunes.

Otherwise, start typing...